# how to create quota from firebase firestore 10 times a month

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm just learning Firebase Firestore, for my Flutter app, how to create a quota, for instance, 10 times a month for an auth user?

My understanding is something like this in cloud function:

```
void useQuota(String userId) async {
  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  
 
  DocumentReference userRef = firestore.collection('users').doc(userId);

 
  firestore.runTransaction((transaction) async {
    DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await transaction.get(userRef);
    
    if (!snapshot.exists) {
      throw Exception("User does not exist!");
    }
    
    int newQuota = snapshot.data()['quota'] - 1;
    
    if (newQuota < 0) {
      throw Exception("No quota left!");
    }

    transaction.update(userRef, {'quota': newQuota});
  });
}
```

At start of month:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.resetQuota = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 0 1 * *').onRun((context) => {
  const usersRef = admin.firestore().collection('users');
  const batch = admin.firestore().batch();
  
  return usersRef.get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      batch.update(doc.ref, {quota: 10});
    });
    
    return batch.commit();
  });
});
```

But I do not have the right clue about this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What do you mean by "create quota"?

Comment: Hi Alex, I mean a user could use 10 times a feature from my app monthly, so I guess each month cloud function should give 10 quota to every user?

Comment: This should be fairly straightfoward; each time a user retrieves data (a feature) increment a counter. When they attempt to retrieve that data each time, check to see if the counter is less than 10. If not, deny usage. It seems like you're kinda trying to do that already. Is there something more?

Comment: Hi, this is what Im trying to achieve, to be clear, do you mean, client will send a request to firebase to inform firebase to increment a counter, and app client will get confirmation from firebase how many counter is used this month, if already more than 10, the client will deny usage? Is it correct way or firebase should deny this usage as cloud function, and in this way it seems there is no need to use cloud function for reset each month, since client is able to handle this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Jay's comment is very clear in my opinion, but I will try to explain it in more detail, so you can see the big picture.

Let's suppose that a feature in your app is represented by the reading of a document. This means that you need to let the user read the content of that document only 10 times a month. Now here comes the counter. To be able to know the number of times a user has seen the content of the document, you need to add/increment a counter. So when a user reads the document for the first time, then you should add a field of type number in the Realtime Database. The schema should look like this:

```
db
|
--- features
     |
     --- $uid
     |    |
     |    --- $docId: 1 //Added
     |
     --- $uid
          |
          --- $docId: 9 //Incremented
```

Please see that under the `$uid` you can store key-value pairs, where the key is the document ID and the value is the actual number of the document reads. Now, what's the flow? When a user reads a document, you have to check if the document ID exists under `db/features/$uid/$docId`. If it doesn't exist it means that the user reads the document for the first time, meaning that you have to add the document ID and the number one, as in the above example. If the document ID already exists, then you should read the corresponding value. If the value is less than ten, then you should let the user read the document and [increment](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#atomic_server-side_increments) the counter. If the counter is already ten, then you should deny the reading of the document.

Why did I use the Realtime Database and not Firestore? That is because the write operation in Firebase Realtime Database is free of charge.

Furthermore, since you say that ten is the maximum number of reads for a month, then you have to reset all counters of all users. In this case, you can [schedule](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/) a [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) to fire at each end of the month to reset the counter. What should that function actually do? It should only delete the entire `features` node. That's it.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the detailed explanation, now I have clear mind what I need to learn and achieve:)

Comment: Hi Alex, in case it is another question for my case about using firestore or rtdb, could you plz check my new question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76785858/should-i-use-firebase-rtdb-or-firestore-for-querying-usage-quota

Comment: For query and check part I updated my question, I am using cloud function to check quota usage and from my flutter app to fire this function, is it correct?

Comment: If you have any other question that derives from this one, then it's considered a new question and should be added separately. So please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you. I just rolled back your question to not create confusion to future visitors.

Comment: I'll take a look at your [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76785858/should-i-use-firebase-rtdb-or-firestore-for-querying-usage-quota) and if I'll know the answer, I'll write to you. Can I help you with other information regarding the initial question?

Comment: Hi Alex, i saw you edit my updated question already, many thanks again for you patient, I will learn and have a try:) As for my new question, I guess I will use both for my case:)

Comment: Give it a try and tell me if it works.